# $\||f|^{2}f\|_{H^{s}}\leq C \|f\|^{2}_{L^{\infty}} \|f\|_{H^{s}}$ for $s>0, f\in H^{s}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

We let $H^{s}(\mathbb R^{n}), (s\in \mathbb R)$  the [Sobolev spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space).
It is well known that: the space $H^{s}(\mathbb R^{n})$ is an algebra with respect to pointwise multiplications, for $s>n/2.$

> **My Question**: Can we expect $\||f|^{2}f\|_{H^{s}}\leq C \|f\|^{2}_{L^{\infty}} \|f\|_{H^{s}}$ for $s>0, f\in H^{s}(\mathbb R)$  (where $C$ is some constant)? If Yes, how to prove it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

For $0<s<1$ this is true in all dimensions $n$, and follows by writing the norm as in integral of divided differences [Leoni, *A first course in Sobolev spaces*, 14.8]
$$
\|f\|_{H^s}^2 \approx \|f\|_{L^2}^2+\iint\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\,dx\,dy \tag{1}
$$
Indeed, (1) shows at once that for any Lipschitz function $\varphi$ fixing $0$ we have  $$\|\varphi\circ f\|_{H^s} \le C(\operatorname{Lip} \varphi)\| f\|_{H^s}\tag{2}$$
The function $\varphi(u)= |u|^2u$ is Lipschitz on the range of $f$.

For $s=1$ the statement also holds in all dimensions $n$, and is easy to prove from the definition.

---

In higher smoothness orders there are issues in dimensions $n>1$. As an illustration: the third derivative of $f^3$ involves $(f')^3$, so we are looking to bound $\int |f'|^6$ in terms of $H^3$ norm of $f$. The Sobolev embedding gives such a bound in low dimensions only; in higher dimensions it fails, and the boundedness of $f$ is of no help here.

On this topic, see [Superposition in homogeneous and vector valued Sobolev spaces](http://www.jointmathematicsmeetings.org/journals/tran/2010-362-11/S0002-9947-2010-05150-5/) by Gérard Bourdaud  and the survey [Composition Operators on Function Spaces with Fractional Order of Smoothness](http://users.minet.uni-jena.de/~sickel/japan(v4).pdf) by Bourdaud and Sickel.

---

But in $n=1$ there is no such issue: all lower derivatives are neatly controlled by higher order derivatives. For integer exponents $s$ direct computation works: the $k$th derivative of $|f|^2 f$ splits into a bunch of terms like $D^a f\ D^b f\ D^cf$ with $a+b+c=k$, and the $L^2$ norms  of all of these are controlled by the $H^k$ norm of $f$.

---

For fractional exponents $s>1$ one can try to differentiate $\lfloor s\rfloor$ times (again, expanding by the product rule) and then use the result for $s\in (0,1)$. However, this looks messy and I'm not quite sure this works out. It's better to use a characterization similar to (1) in which the first difference $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is replaced by higher order difference $|\Delta^k f|$. Then you can work with $|\Delta^k (|f|^2f)|$ algebraically, and  stick the estimates into the integral formula. A reference for the higher-order difference characterization of Sobolev spaces   is *Integral Representations of Functions and Imbedding Theorems* by Besov, Il'in, Nikolski.